# Probability Two Independent Samples of Different Size Have Some Intersection

Tags: self-study, sampling, independence

I've been working on generating a probability rule for taking two random samples without replacement and finding a given amount of overlap between the two.  So far I've worked through simple cases like considering 3, 4, or 5 tickets in a bag each with an equal probability of being drawn.  Then in one sample we could pull x1 of those tickets, and in the other we would pull x2, where x1 and x2 are known ahead of time but not necessarily equal.

Working through these simpler cases with an event-counting approach I've determined the denominator of the probability should always be (N choose x1)*(N choose x2), since 1/that number will be the probability of any specific x1 and x2 being drawn.  What I'm having trouble with now is generating a rule for the numerator of this fraction - how many ways can we succeed at finding k overlap if we've drawn x1 and x2.

In the case of 3 tickets, and we want to know the probability of one ticket being found in both x1 = 2 and x2 = 1, I've found there are 6 successful outcomes out of 9 possible.  The same goes for when x1 and x2 are both 2.

In a case with 4 tickets, if x1 is 2 and x2 is 1 again, this probability is 12/24, if x1 & x2 are both 2, 24/36.

Going up to cases with 5 tickets, I've looked at cases where {x1 = 2, x2 = 1}; {x1 = 4, x2 = 1}; {x1 = 4, x2 = 2}.  And in each of those (respectively) I found there were 20 successes from 50 outcomes, 20 successes in 25 outcomes, and 20 successes in 50 outcomes.

Again, I found the pattern in the denominator to be (N choose x1)*(N choose x2) but have been unable to see the pattern in the numerator when changing x1 & x2.  I think there should also be some relation between the union of x1 and x2 against the size of N (since there's a certain choice of x1 and x2 that guarantees at least k successes between the two), but the rule isn't apparent to me yet.

Any help anyone could provide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This reads like a standard [capture-recapture](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=capture+recapture) analysis.

Comment: In a sense yes, but the capture-recapture answers I've seen here so far are usually trying to estimate the population size N given k, x1 and x2.  I want to know the probability of finding k in both x1 and x2 given N, x1, and x2.

Comment: The estimation relies on those probabilities: they are given by the hypergeometric function.

Comment: @p-lally Imagine you have a population of N black balls. You draw $n_1$ balls and paint them white (i.e. mark them so that you know that they're the ones you drew previously) and mix them back in. Now you have a population of white and black balls. Next, you draw $n_2$ balls out of this collection and count the number of white balls in the second sample. ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution